# What is a valid use case for one thread accquring a semaphore and another one releasing it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

A difference between a Linux semaphore and mutex is that mutex can be unlocked by the thread who locked it. But then, what is a use case of one thread locking and another one unlocking it ?

Comment: Such use cases (semaphore is locked by one thread but unlocked from other one) are used when **other than "critical section"** is needed for synchronize threads. Questions "give me an example" are badly suited for Stack Overflow, because they have *many possible answers* without "better one" criteria.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129299/syncronizing-2-threads-c-linux/44131518#44131518

Comment: Yes, a semaphore can be (ab)used as a lock of sorts, but that's not generally their intended purpose - they're more intended for regulating access to a limited resource than for providing mutual exclusion semantics.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowing of thread or process to access specific Synchronised section at a time till Semaphore value becomes 0.
Programming use case:
This is not the way semaphores are used in the producer-consumer scenario. The standard solution is to use two counting semaphores, one for the empty slots (initialized to the number of available slots), and another for the filled slots (initialized to 0).